# Rails 参加予定のイベント一覧を取得するAPI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

Railsのフォロー機能があるアプリで、特定のユーザーが参加するイベント一覧をユーザー情報の画面で表示するためのAPIを作成したいです。 
ユーザーが作成したイベントの一覧はcurrent_user.events.allで取得できると思うのですが、ある特定のユーザーが参加するイベントの一覧はどのようなメソッドで取得すれば良いのでしょうか？ 
また、フォロー機能のあるイベント管理アプリを作る時のベストプラクティスなどがあれば教えていただけると幸甚です！

User has_many: events(イベント作成者としてのユーザー) 
Event has_many: users, through: :participations 
のようにモデル定義しています。

Comment: 素朴にこの質問を読む限りでは、特定のユーザーのIDがわかるのであれば、user.events とすればモデルとしてはデータが取得できるのではないかと思ったのですが、どのユーザーを表示したらよいかも現状では設計されてないということなのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

イベント参加などの情報がＤＢでどのように保存されているかによって回答は変わりますが、
Userモデルにその情報があるなら、User.findなどで対象のユーザーのレコードを取得しればよいのでは？